# Why cannot I see in IBM Data Studio a temporary table created by an application?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, db2

I am using the code below to connect to an IBM DB2 database and perform Bulkcopy. After it executes `CMD.EXECUTENONQUERY()` method, I try to verify whether the table is created or not in the IBM Data Studio client interface, but it says "Table name undefined". Can someone explain why I cannot see the table?

```
 public void ExecuteBulkCopy(string connectionString, DataTable source, string destinationTableName,
        int timeOut)
    {
        var schema = "DEVPROC";
        var procName = $"{schema}.FSVPTEMP001";
        var commandText =
            "declare global temporary table TEMP_TRY_NEW(CPK_ID CHAR(25), VDR_ID INTEGER,P_ID CHAR(15),MPP_CPK_K_ID DECIMAL(12),MPP_P_K_ID DECIMAL(12),ODBMS_VDR_KEY_ID DECIMAL(12),DEL_ELIG_DT DATE,RW_CRT_TS TIMESTAMP,RW_CRT_PRC_ID CHAR(11),RW_UDT_TS TIMESTAMP,RW_UDT_PRC_ID CHAR(11))ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;";

        var connection = new DB2Connection(connectionString);
        {
            var cmd = new DB2Command(commandText, connection);
            {
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                var copy = new DB2BulkCopy(connection);

                copy.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName;
                copy.BulkCopyTimeout = timeOut;


                copy.WriteToServer(source);

                copy.Close();

                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Temporary tables only exist for the current session (connection), so if you're looking for that table in Data Studio, you won't find it, because that is using another connection.  You could try running another DB2Command (within your code there) to select back from the table.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I got it... It all works very well inside one session.

Comment: I mean inside one Connection...